# gtag linker for Cross Domain

Tags: google-people-api, gtag.js

I'm trying to set a linked in a URL with the new gtag, but I can't see the code of the link in the URL.

I set google analytics like this:

```
gaScript.setAttribute('async', 'true');
gaScript.setAttribute('src', `https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${ trackingID }`);
and
gaScript2.innerText = `window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}gtag(\'js\', new Date());gtag(\'config\', \'${ trackingID }\', {\'linker\': {'domains': [\'${crossDomain}\']}});`;
```

HI have this:

```
const decorateURL = (url: string) => {
    let destinationLink = false;
    if (ga) {
       let tracker = ga.getAll()[0];
       let linker = new window.gaplugins.Linker(tracker);
       destinationLink = linker.decorate(url);
    }

    return (destinationLink ? url + '?' + destinationLink : url);
}
```

and the call:

```
window.location.assign(decorateURL(data.redirectUrl));
```

Currently, o got an error saying:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ga is not defined
```

Can someone help in order to define a URL with gtag?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think it might be a question of timing, because if you go to a website where google analytics is installed (either with the ga syntax or gtag) you are able to run `ga.getAll()` on the console and get a result. This means that at a certain point after loading your page, ga will be defined